# Webscraping with selenium, click() line only works after x number of tries

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Hi I have a script that scrapes a website based on filters, this was working fine up until the latest chrome update and chromedriver update and then one of the filters was failing to click.

I have a try and except loop that repeats for 10 tries, sometimes this is enough sometimes and other times I need > 15 clicks of the same line of code for it to eventually work.

Here is my code to initiate the webpage:

```
from selenium import webdriver

url='https://www.marketscreener.com/stock-exchange/calendar/finance/'
options=webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_prefs = {}
options.experimental_options["prefs"]=chrome_prefs
chrome_prefs["profile.defaul_content_settings"] = {"popups":1}
options.add_argument('--disable-browser-side-navigation')
options.add_argument('--disable-infobars')
options.add_argument('--disable-extensions')
options.add_argument('--disable-popup-blocking')
options.add_argument('--disable-notifications')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'foo.exe',options=options)
```

after I log in using my credentials I try this line of code:

```
driver.find_element_by_id("selCountry").click()
```

which opens up the country filter drop down menu. The majority of times it takes an arbitrary number >10 tries for it to eventually work.

I am using chrome version 87.0.4280.141 and its chromedriver with python 3.7.

Can anyone provide a better solution to my problem or maybe an explanation on why it suceedes after x number of tries?

Comment: Have you tried using time.sleep()? Sometimes, the element that you want to click might not work immediately. The element may have an event listener bind to it asynchronously, so it needs to have something occur on the server side before it's actually clickable. Human users may not notice, but a bot that doesn't need to drag an actual mouse can get there before its ready.

Comment: @KyleAlm yup i have put various sleeps before and after that line of code

Comment: How does it "fail"? What's the exception? What does it do when you step through the code one line at a time, slowly? How long is your sleep before your find_element_by_id() call?